# Where is documentation on the embedding API for the Ruby interpreter?

Tags: c, ruby, api, documentation, embedding

I am looking for a comprehensive, online, documentation resource regarding the embedding of the Ruby interpreter into C or C++ programs, and the API(s) for that purpose.

The section on this in the Pickaxe book is quite good, but my version refers to Ruby 1.8 and I am interested in the range of current ruby versions i.e. 1.8.x, 1.9.x, and 2.0, and there are a number of differences between the handling of embedding across that range of versions.

For reference, the Ruby interpreter in question is the main Ruby interpreter from http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

I have found on stackoverflow a number of specific questions  related to aspects of this [(error handling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618957/ruby-interpreter-embed-in-c-code) [(state reset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940610/reset-state-of-embedded-ruby-interpreter) [(c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626333/embedding-a-ruby-interpreter-in-a-c-app): what I seek is the documentation, if any, from which such answers were gleaned!

There is a Ruby 1.8 and Unix centric [guide](http://aeditor.rubyforge.org/ruby_cplusplus/index.html), too.

There is documentation for the C API of Ruby, used in writing extensions, and also in embedding. This can be found on github [(ruby 2.0)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/README.EXT) and [(ruby 1.9)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/README.EXT) but handling variations in version seems left to the reader

The chapter on [extending ruby](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf) in the Pickaxe book is now available online as a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are looking for, I guess, but have you had a look at [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby)? A ruby version specifically meant for embedding into C code. This might be easier to work with than the full MRI ruby interpreter.

Comment: Looks like that interpreter is still very much a work in progress. Of course, it would be of great interest once finished and shipping!

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately that was and still is a major problem with Ruby. The japanese developers are very bad in english and therefore don't like to write documentation. The best documentation is only available in japanese.

A lot change for Ruby 2.0 and we have to wait until someone writes a book about it. But this isn't financed by any publishing company anymore (they want quick beginner level or scientific/educational books).

I have to hold back to not add a political rant about why we have such a terrible situation in software engineering at the moment.

Comment: They're actually quite fine in English. They just don't document any more than anybody else.